# QGIS expression: Extract attribute of nearest point

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, expression, qgis-expression

I have two layer of points: 'Measure' (> 2000 points) and 'Control' (5 points).

For each control and measure point, I have a "depth" attribute.
I would like to display on symbology of "depth" attribute with the closest point.

For now I can draw a line to the closest point:

[image: 1]

Using this geometry expression inside 'Control' symbology:

```
make_line ( 
    $geometry, 
    overlay_nearest(
        'Measure', 
        $geometry, 
        limit:=2
    )[1]
)
```

Now I want to display the difference of depth on this line (Sorry it is in french): [image: 2]

But i don t know how to extract the attribute "depth" from the geometry point I have in expression:

[image: 3]

In this screen, `'resultPoints_e74212d8_6062_4c65_bdda_cfebd8bd679f'` is my 'Measure' layer.

The real question is: **How to extract attribute from a geometry point ?**

In reality, i need to replace the 0 in this formula with the depth attribute of the closest point:

```
'XY:'||round(length(transform(make_line ( $geometry, overlay_nearest('resultPoints_e74212d8_6062_4c65_bdda_cfebd8bd679f', $geometry, limit:=2)[1]),
'EPSG:4326',
'EPSG:2832')),2)||'m - Z:'||round(0-"depth")||'m'
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand everything, but in the expression `overlay_nearest` instead of `$geometry` (which extract geometry) did you try to put the field `Depth`?

Comment: Yes, i have ``NULL`` as result with formula: ``overlay_nearest('resultPoints_e74212d8_6062_4c65_bdda_cfebd8bd679f', "depth")[0]``

Comment: This works for me, but you have to remove `limit: = 2` and take the first value of the array `[0] `

Comment: Working in blank example but not in my project. Thank you a lot for the usage of ``overlay_nearest `` that i missed!

Comment: Ok, the issue was EPSG code. With same EPSG code, there is no problem!

Answer (score 2):

(The credit of the answer go to @pigreco) (You can copy paste the answer and i will delete this one)

To get the attribute 'depth' of the nearest point of another layer in a qgis expression:

```
overlay_nearest('<my_layer_id>', "depth")[0]
```

Replace `<my_layer_id>` in the formula with your layer id to compare.

To avoid issues try to have same EPSG codes in your two layers.